# How to send commands to texts and buttons of webkit browser in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, automation, webkit.net

I have an application where I used `WebBrowser` to embed a browser. On a button click form my application I should navigate to a website ([archive.org](https://archive.org/)) and write a text into the browse history textbox (id = "wwmurl") of this website, then simulate the click of "BROWSE HISTORY" button.

I know how to simulate writing a text into a form, but I didn't know how to access a specific text box in a web page loaded in webkit browser.

Sorry for not adding code, but I don't think any piece of my code would be valuable here, since I want a hint to know how to make this right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a button click event handler, and then create a click on the other button. This page summarizes the APIs for that.

http://www.speakcomputers.com/Windows-Forms-Programming/VB/Button.aspx

**Creating a Click Event for the VB.NET Button control.**

```
AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf button_Click
```

**Responding to the VB.NET Button Click event.**

```
Private Sub button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked")
End Sub
```